# How can I properly profile JavaScript in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, profiling

I'm currently profiling my JavaScript with the Chrome-DevTools.

Since I'm developing for iPad etc. as well I want to use the Safari Debugger.
I realized that the "slowest" functions identified by Safari's profiler are actually the ones which are called most often.

Since Chrome gives me different values, I think this is due to profiler-overhead and precise invocation-counting, not because they are actually slow.

Safari's profiler seems useless to me, therefore.

Is there away around this? Can I get "realistic" values with Safari?

Answer (score 1):

See this [URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Instruments/Instruments.html) :

#### Timelines Tab :

It is a good profiling via safari .

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Art/profile_javascript_2x.png))</sub>

If you want to handle the output , we advise to use a command line such [v8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/adminIntro):

```
out/ia32.release/d8 --prof script.js
```